# Is $\Phi(-a(x+b))+\Phi(-a(x-b))$ log-concave in $x$ over the interval $x \in [0, \infty)$?

Tags: pr.probability, differential-calculus

Let $f(x)=\Phi(-a(x+b))+\Phi(-a(x-b))$, where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the c.d.f of the standard normal, and $a>0$.

I would like to know if $\partial^2 \ln(f(x))/\partial x^2<0$  over the interval $x \in [0, \infty)$. I believe this is true, but I am having difficulty proving it. I would be immensely thankful to anyone who might help.

Comment: (i) Did you mean $f(x)=\Phi(-a(x+b))+\Phi(-a(x-b))$ but missed a closing parenthesis? (ii) Did you mean to prove that $\partial^2 \ln(f(x))/\partial x^2<0$? Otherwise what is your $\kappa$? (iii) "Prove that" is rude and may create an impression that this is homework. You should rephrase this.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I changed the wording and corrected the (quite embarrassing!) mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\num{\operatorname{num}}\newcommand\den{\operatorname{den}}$This is not true in general. E.g.,
$$\frac{\partial^2 \ln f(x)}{\partial x^2}=0.16522\ldots>0$$
at $(a,b,x)=(1,-5,-4)$.

---

The OP has changed the question, by adding the condition $x\ge0$, thus invalidating the answer above.

After the change, the answer becomes positive.

Indeed, by a horizontal rescaling of the graph of $f$, without loss of generality (wlog) $a=1$.  Also, wlog $b>0$, since $f$ is even in $b$.

It is enough to show that
\begin{equation}
    r:=L'=\frac\num\den
\end{equation}
is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$, where
\begin{equation}
    L:=\ln f,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \num(x):=-h(-b-x)-h(b-x),\quad\den(x):=H(-b-x)+H(b-x),
\end{equation}
and $h$ and $H$ denote, respectively, the pdf and the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

Consider the "derivative ratio"
\begin{equation}
    \rho(x):=\frac{\num'(x)}{\den'(x)}= \frac{b \left(e^{2 b x}-1\right)}{e^{2 b x}+1}-x. 
\end{equation}
Note that
\begin{equation}
    \rho''(x)=-\frac{8 b^3 e^{2 b x} \left(e^{2 b x}-1\right)}{\left(e^{2 b
   x}+1\right)^3}<0 
\end{equation}
(for $x>0$). So, the function $\rho$ is concave. Also, $\rho(0)=0$. Hence, $\rho$ is up-down on $[0,\infty)$ -- that is, for some $c\in[0,\infty]$ the function $\rho$ is increasing on $[0,c]$ and decreasing on $[c,\infty)$. Note also that $\num(\infty-)=0=\den(\infty-)$.

The crucial point of this proof is the use of the l'Hospital-type rule for monotonicity given in line 3 of [Table 4.1](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/157_05_JIPAM/157_05.pdf), which now implies that, just as the "derivative ratio" $\rho$, the function $r$ is up-down on $[0,\infty)$. But
\begin{equation}
    r'(0)=-\frac{4h(b)^2}{(H(-b)+H(b))^2}<0. 
\end{equation}
Thus, $r$ decreasing on $[0,\infty)$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to specify that the domain of $f(x)$ is $[0,\infty)$. I believe this this is true for $x$ non-negative. I modified the question.

Comment: @user3679030 : The OP should not change the question so as to invalidate a valid existing answer. In this case, I have answered the changed question as well. However, in the future you should prepare your questions much, much more carefully, so as not to waste other people's time.

Comment: Thank you! And my apologies again, I'm still familiarizing myself with how to ask questions.

Comment: Rereading the proof, it appears to me it does not apply for $b$ small. When $b$ is small, $\rho$ becomes strictly decreasing (instead of up-down). I tried to use Table 3.2 of the linked article to prove that the result still hold when $\rho$ is decreasing, but I can't seem to make it work. I wonder if there is something I am missing? Thank you for your help once again.

Comment: @user3679030 : The definition of up-down in my answer differs slightly from the corresponding definition of $\nearrow\searrow$ in the paper: in the answer, $c$ is allowed to be one of the endpoints. Table 4.1 in the paper will work as well when the endpoints are allowed. Formally, when $\rho$ is decreasing, use Proposition 4.1 in the paper.

Comment: Brilliant, I had missed that subtlety. Thank you for the clarification.